# How can I move scroll rect by children inside other child which is in content rect transform of scroll rect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rect, scrollrect

I have a problem, because I group something by the months, and when I open the month something deep in this month is visibility.

Parent of months is content in scroll rect component, and I can move it by scrolling mouse on months, but when I want to scroll by the children I can`t make it.

This is screenshot of my hierarchy in unity:

[image: screenshot from unity hierarchy]

[image]

I can scroll only by the first object(month), how can i repair it, without huge changes in hierarchy, because hierarchy using a looong script which I have to change?

I will mention that I can`t use vertical layout group and content size fitter, because its make a lot of problems with scrolling in this example, and I resigned of use it.

I was looking in yt, and a lot of unity forums, but I can`t find any interesting information about my problem.

Comment: I would suggest fixing the question formatting. I also have some difficulty understanding the question. A general approach is to describe: 1) What is your overall goal 2) What have you tried 3) What result you got 4) what result you expected.

Comment: So you want to scroll by month and then when a month is chosen scroll by it's child objects?